# Should I use <table> or <div>?

Tags: web-development, html, web-design

I am making a time-sheet portion of a website and I was wondering if using  to create the time-sheet portion is an appropriate usage of table or would div be a better use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tables are appropriate for creating *actual tables* (AKA grids) as part of your HTML.  A timesheet would be a good example of a grid.

The "don't use tables; use divs" meme is about how it used to be common to massively abuse `<TABLE>` elements with manual column widths to lay out the page, which can be done much better with divs.  But for actual tables, the `<TABLE>` element is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Tables are still popular in email layouts, however. Because Outlook is authored by sociopaths who thought word's HTML rendering engine would be a swell thing to use all the way up to 2013. You can't really not use tables for any non-trivial layout, sadly.